# Get the latest activities in a pageable list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm creating a website and on the main page, I want to see the latest updates (latest comments, events, etc..)
These entities have a common property called `Created` (`DateTime`). I want to get a pageable list from these activities.

I have 3 solutions:

1. Create a new "join table": `Id, Comment_Id, Event_Id, ..., Created`.
   So i can say `GetTheLatestActivities(pageSize, pageIndex)` and when I get this list I can access the entities via navigation properties. The problem with this approach is the data redundancy (+1 table (and complicated query?))
2. Using Table per Hierarchy (TPH): every "activities" would be stored in one table, so I can filter the records easily. The problem with this approach is my sql table scheme would be denormalized, and the data integrity would be weak (because of the fields would be nullables to support inheritance)
3. GetAll entities (`Comments`, `Events` etc..), and filter this concatenated list with LINQ (every object support `ICreated` interface so I can `OrderBy` Date and use `Skip/Take`). The obvious problem is the performance, I would get all of the records from the db in every requests, and filter on the "client side".

I think the best is the first one, or are there any better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view that presents a union of the common fields:

```
select t1.Table1Id as Id, t1.Name as Description, t1.Job, t1.Created from Table1 t1
union all
select t2.Table2Id as Id, t2.Description, null as Job, t2.Created from Table2 t2
```

This view could be added to your model and you can do the normal paging Skip/Take against it.

Comment: I need access not just the common fields (basically there is only one: `Created`), but  I think I could use a view instead of the "join table"

Comment: I've edited the above example to show that you can include columns that only pertain to one of the source tables, with the other tables returning null for that column.